# Laravel blade print

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a simple piece of code where I want the street address + the house number printed. With this piece it will only print the street address.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<td>{{ $user->street, $user->house_nr }}</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blade doesn't totally support echoing multiple variables. Double braces are converted to `echo e(...)` in your case that is:

```
echo e($user->street, $user->house_nr);
```

You could use raw output for echoing multiple variables:

```
{!! $user->street, $user->house_nr !!}
```

Which would compile to:

```
echo $user->street, $user->house_nr;
```

However then you'll lose the escaping.

---

What you probably want is either:

```
{{ $user->street }}, {{ $user->house_nr }}
```

Or with string concatenation:

```
{{ $user->street.', '.$user->house_nr }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code between the bracers is php.

```
<td>{{ $user->street }}, {{ $user->house_nr }}</td>
```